# PhoneGap: Does it know what libraries won't run on target platforms?

Tags: java, android, gwt, cordova

For reasons I don't quite (yet) understand, there's some Java libraries/packages that just won't work correctly (or even run) when deployed to an Android device. Libraries like Guice or Apache Camel.

Not being an iOS, .NET or JavaScript developer, I don't know if iPhones, Windows Phones or Blackberries suffer the from same/similar problems.

Irregardless, we have at least 1 scenario (Java/Android) where PhoneGap is generating code for a target platform that *may not be runnable* on that platform. So I ask: does PhoneGap know each target platform well enough to not generate native code that won't run on it?

In other words, Apache Camel (for example) will not run on Android devices. What happens when I use GWT to compile a Camel route (with endpoints) down into JavaScript, and then use PhoneGap to wrap it and package an APK? Will PhoneGap say "hey, this is Camel stuff; you can't run on Android devices" and fail it or is there the possibility of leaking "un-runnable" code into PhoneGap apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself, GWT compiles your Java code to Javascript.

So phonegap only sees Javascript code, it will not be able to tell that this is compiled from Java (it does not contain any java source anymore). It will treat it as a normal web apps and it will just execute the generated javascript source.